# Negative Integer ValuError, Append but not Write

Tags: python, file, integer, append

My first problem is that, When i enter tex -10 the except ValueError doesn't run, only the first input runs again, but if i enter (-10) then the ValuError does run.I want the ValueError to run when I enter -10, a negative number without a paraentes

```
while True:
          try:
          number = int(input("Area?"))
       if number>0:
            break
  except ValueError: 
           print("That was not a positive number") ##
```

My second question is that this function only works when I have "a", append, and not when I have Write, does anyone know why, and How I can fix it? I would like to write to a file.

```
def list_to_file():
             file=open("file.txt","a") 
             file.write("\n")
             file.write("".join(str(lista)))
```

Comment: `break` does not equal `raise exception`

Comment: Hmm isn't that like code repetition? Could I solve the whole thing in another way don't you think? @TehTris

Comment: OH wait i see what you are doing... lemme write an answer... but please correct your whitespace while i write this.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem, it sounds like you want to raise a value error then except it.

```
number = int(input("Area?"))
while True:
    try:
        if number > 0:
            break
        else:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        number = int(input("Please enter a positive number"))
```

As for the second question I was unable to write to a file when it was a small "lista" but was able when it was large. I posed the question here and got an answer that worked

[Python won't write small object to file but will with large object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536918/python-wont-write-small-object-to-file-but-will-with-large-object)

In short, you have to close the file with file.close() when you're finished writing to it.

```
def list_to_file():
     file=open("file.txt","w") 
     file.write("\n")
     file.write("".join(str(lista)))
     file.close()
```

So if you were having the same issue this should do the trick.

To make a new file for each iteration, make a count that will be incremented each iteration, and send it to the printing method. Then use that count to make a unique file name like this:

```
def list_to_file(count, lista):
    file=open("file_"  + str(count) + ".txt","w") 
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("".join(str(lista)))
    file.close()

allLists = list of all your listas
count = 1
for thisList in allLists:
    list_to_print(count, thisList)
    count +=1
```

Comment: It is working thanks to you!, you illustrated how to fix it perfectly:) @Malonge Do you have any clue about the other problem?

Comment: I am working on that though I am oddly having trouble as well. You should click the up arrow on my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do is to write to a table to a file, but the problem is that I keep adding and adding results to that file, I want to write to it every new time, so I want to use "w" instead but it doesn't work.. Would really be super if you figure it out! Thanks anyways @Malonge

Comment: Intereesting. I just got it to work for me. Just to clarify, do you want to update the same old file every time or make a new file for each iteration?

Comment: I want to make a new file for each iteration, but I'm not able to do so. I only able update the same old file, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting your try: except: statement wrong. it should look like this:

```
try:
    1/0
except:
    print("the exception happened")
```

notice how try is directly above except... in yours it looks like this:

```
#your code
while True:
       try:
          number = int(input("State the number of latitudes you want to calculate energy for?"))
       if number>0:
            break
except ValueError: 
           print("That was not a positive number") ##
```

you got an except statement thats hanging out below a while statement with no try statement that belongs to it.

the way that you probably want to do it is something along these lines:

```
while True:
    try:
        #some sort of statement here that is going to throw an exception like 1/0 ( cant divide by zero bro )
    except:
        print("cant divide b zero bro")
        #some statement that you want to happen after the above exception is thrown
        break
```

in addition to that, YOUR `break` is not an exception inducing statement, all it does is stop a loop from finishing. the line that says "break" should say something like

```
while True:
    try:
        if _some_sort_of_logic_not_fufilled:
            raise Exception("some exception text if you want") #you could use your ValueError here also since ValueError is derived from Exception
    except:
        print "see how it got here?"
        break # this would go here if you want it to STOP the loop after it gets the exception, or dont put break if you want it to keep going... but a while True loop... you probably wnat to eventually break out of...
```

Comment: That still doesn't, following the example you gave last. @TehTris