# Python won't write small object to file but will with large object

Tags: python, file-io

This is quite confusing. When I have the following code:

```
lista = [i for i in range(10)]          

file=open("file.txt","a") 
file.write("\n")
file.write("".join(str(lista)))
```

The output "file.txt" will be an empty file with zero bytes. But when I increase the size of the string to be written ...

```
lista = [i for i in range(10000)]      # Or larger    

file=open("file.txt","a") 
file.write("\n")
file.write("".join(str(lista)))
```

It works fine. Although it doesn't make sense to me, it is behaving as if there is a minimum file size for writing to an output file. Why is this? Is this problem unique to my computing environment?

Any help is appreciated.
I am working on Mac OS Yosemite. Python 3.

Comment: Works in Ubuntu and python 3.4. Also probably you want `"".join(map(str,lista))`

Comment: Are you closing the files after both operations?

Comment: Probably a buffering issue. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: It is working for me, these are the contents of my file.txt: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: @kartikg3 I am deleting the file between runs.

Comment: You shoudl still close it. It is good practice. Prevents all sorts of wierd OS locking stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should invoke the `close` method after writing something to a file.

```
lista = [i for i in range(10)]          

file=open("file.txt","a") 
file.write("\n")
file.write("".join(str(lista)))
file.close()
```

Or use the `with` statement to close the file automatically：

```
lista = [i for i in range(10)]          

with open("file.txt","a")  as file:
    file.write("\n")
    file.write("".join(str(lista)))
```

Comment: @Malonge the `write` method does not really write something to the file,it just wrote the data to a buffer,you should use the close method to tell it to flush the data to the file and then close it.

Comment: or even `file.flush()` would have resolved his issue ... but yeah with or close is a better solution in general (+1)